# If Else statement in Android not working

Tags: java, android

Here I am creating a simple Droid LoginApp, which simply tells login successfull or not. But the if statement is not giving me the desired result.

Following is the code : 
 MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.login1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
public EditText t1,t2;
public Button b1;
String user,pass;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    t2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    b1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0)  
{
    user = t1.getText().toString();
    pass = t2.getText().toString();


        if (((user.equals("user")) && (pass.equals("user"))))
            {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
        t1.setText("");
        t2.setText("");

    }

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="fill_vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="Username"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text" >

    <requestFocus />

</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:text="Password"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />




<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Login" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

While I run the App, on clicking the Login button, the if statement does not give a correct result.. I simply don't know where is the error.

Comment: please tell me the error, or output

Comment: String comparison should be done with `.equals()`, not `==`. It should be `if( user.equals("user") )`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java/513839#513839).

Comment: I think you have one more bracket than you need `}`

Comment: To expand on Roddy's comment, `==` tests whether 2 objects are the same object.  `.equals` for String tests the value.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas is right. and it is really hard to read, you should reformat your code

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas: Sir Thanku soo much the code now works correctly.

Comment: @simon Didn't know .equals() works only for String. This indeed clears my huge doubt.

Comment: @k-mera: Edited it is!!

Comment: It doesn't work **only** for String.  Most classes implement their own `equals` method for this purpose since `==` always means "is the same".  Two objects being the same object is very different to two objects having the same data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you should compare strings with "equals()" and not with "==".

Replace:

```
user == "user"
```

With:

```
user.equals("user")
```

And also, I think there's no need for this extra line you have:

```
if (arg0.findViewById(R.id.button1)==b1)
```

^ Why are you checking this?

Comment: I was checking it weather the if statement after actually works on button press but then now it's clear since the xml documents contains the onClick method, so including in java code makes no sense now.

Answer (score -1):

use this code, for click command

```
b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        user = t1.getText().toString();
        if (user.equals("user")){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Sucessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for updating it. Much better. Just because the OP did it that way doesn't make it right.